# got a "Notebook error: PermissionError" while generating sphinx doc from jupyter notebook in virtualenv

Tags: templates, jupyter-notebook, virtualenv, python-sphinx, nbconvert

I've got a notebook that can be generated as root with or without virtualenv, but it fails when generated as a standard user.

```
$ make html
reading sources... [100%] notebooks/demo_short                                                                                                                                                
Notebook error:
PermissionError in notebooks/demo_short.ipynb:
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/share/jupyter/nbconvert/templates/rst.tpl'
Makefile:19: recipe for target 'html' failed

$ sphinx-build -M html "." "_build" -v
[...]
  File "/home/with_home/p3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 171, in get_source
    f = open_if_exists(filename)
  File "/home/with_home/p3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/utils.py", line 154, in open_if_exists
    return open(filename, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/share/jupyter/nbconvert/templates/rst.tpl'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

[...]
  File "/home/with_home/p3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/docutils/readers/__init__.py", line 77, in parse
    self.parser.parse(self.input, document)
  File "/home/with_home/p3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nbsphinx.py", line 869, in parse
    str(e))
nbsphinx.NotebookError: PermissionError in notebooks/demo_short.ipynb:
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/share/jupyter/nbconvert/templates/rst.tpl'

Notebook error:
PermissionError in notebooks/demo_short.ipynb:
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/share/jupyter/nbconvert/templates/rst.tpl'
```

I think the path indicated is wrong as it should point to somewhere in my virtualenv, but I'm not sure.

In case it helps, I tried the command `jupyter nbconvert notebooks/demo_short.ipynb` from the virtualenv. With root, its ok, but with a standard user, I've got :

```
[...]
  File "/home/with_home/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/templateexporter.py", line 78, in get_source
    return self.loader.get_source(environment, template)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 171, in get_source
    f = open_if_exists(filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/jinja2/utils.py", line 154, in open_if_exists
    return open(filename, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/share/jupyter/nbconvert/templates/html/full.tpl'
```

any pointer is welcome as i don't know if the pb come from sphinx, jupyter, nbconvert, nbsphinx or the template.

Answer (score 2):

Downgrading nbconvert to 5.6.1, fixed the Permission issue for me.

Comment: see also https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/issues/1430#issuecomment-872039410

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure nbconvert is under /usr/local/share/jupyter/nbconvert?
I've faced the same issue. Removing /usr/local/share/jupyter/ did the trick.

Comment: For me it doesn't.
Do you used a virtual env ? I do not understand why using virtualenv, I've got something outside.

Comment: I did.
Try creating your venv with --no-site-packages + try using yourvenv/bin/pip rather than just "pip" for installing dependencies + check the contents of PYTHONPATH when you activate your venv.
Also it's probably not a great idea to run stuff as root then as regular user as it might create files that the regular user won't be allowed to delete.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to **`~/.local/share/`**, remove the Jupyter directory using **`rm -rf Jupyter`** and try opening jupyter notebook again.

Comment: Also need to run "jupyter lab build"

Comment: i deleted this, but it recreated again and same error

Answer (score 0):

I just print in Terminal:

> sudo jupyter notebook --allow-root

After that enter password and Jupyter Notebook is ready for work.